# EntityManager holds on to a deleted entity

Tags: jpa, openjpa

In one transaction I run

```
delete from OdpObjectScheduleEntity e where e.id = 956101
```

Then, in another transaction (and the logs show that it started after the previous one was committed) I tried to persist a new `OdpObjectScheduleEntity` with id 956101, but got an exception:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: An object of type "ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa.entity.OdpObjectScheduleEntity" with oid "956101" already exists in this context; another cannot be persisted.
FailedObject: ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa.entity.OdpObjectScheduleEntity@3ad41caa
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.checkForDuplicateId(BrokerImpl.java:5075)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2651)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2571)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2554)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2458)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1077)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:716)[106:org.apache.openjpa:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:177)[58:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa.repository.RepositoryImpl$36.run(RepositoryImpl.java:2167)[157:ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa:0.1.0]
    at ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.api.CheckedRunnable.call(CheckedRunnable.java:13)[155:ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.api:0.1.0]
    at ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.api.CheckedRunnable.call(CheckedRunnable.java:1)[155:ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.api:0.1.0]
    at ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa.repository.RepositoryImpl.transact(RepositoryImpl.java:879)[157:ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa:0.1.0]
    ... 52 more
```

Is this legal behavior?

Comment: Why are you trying to persist an entity with an already assigned id? This should be not allowed, the id is assigned automatically by the persistence provider upon `persist` method call.

Comment: @remigio This is a shared primary key (`@OneToOne @Id`), not an automatically generated one.

Comment: Can you post your entity annotations? Normally in JPA you delete objects by calling `entityManager.remove(object)`, why are you using a delete query?

Comment: I would suggest turning on openjpa.Log=SQL=trace to help you understand what is going on. I suspect that the EM you're using already had a reference to the Entity which you removed in a separate transaction.

Comment: @remigio To avoid an extra query selecting the object just to delete it. Of course, 1) this isn't critical for performance, and 2) I could likely avoid the query by using `EntityManager.getReference()`, so I could try this.

Comment: @Rick's comment is pertinent, what's the meaning of `"it started after the previous one was committed"`, are you in the same method and call the `persist` method after committing the `delete` manually or are you invoking the two methods in separate threads, are you working with enterprise beans with a common entity manager or is yours a desktop application? To try to guess an answer we need more details.

Comment: @remigio I understood Rick's comment to mean that the EM _is_ allowed to hold on to an entity which is deleted by a delete query, and after thinking a bit realized that it couldn't be done otherwise. That's all I was asking about.